# Did not getting any sellerList in response using ebay sandbox?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ebay-api

Did not getting any `sellerList` in response using ebay sandbox?

```
ItemType[] items = getSellerList.getEntireSellerList();
```

Getting items length empty.

What would be the reason ?

Comment: Can you add all code, please?

Answer (score 0):

you have to define EndTimeFrom and EndTimeTo or StartTimeFrom and StartTimeTo in params to get ebay seller's product.
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html